# To Install and Configure SharePoint 2007 for Office Document Collaboration

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-2007

I have just installed SharePoint 2007 ( no config yet), and would like to get it work on Microsoft Office document collaboration.

Basically I want to be able to use SharePoint as the central repository for Microsoft Word, excel etc. So I need to configure my sharepoint app so that it can check in/ checkout all these documents.

Any ideas or pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint requires no special configuration to enable document collaboration. Just install it according to the documentation and you will be ready to create sites and document libraries where you can check in your documents.

Comment: Mostly it just works. Ensure you have a document library in the site and the settings of the library are pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you would like a more integrated experience, set up [My Sites](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101087481033.aspx). When your users first visit their My Site, they will receive a prompt asking them if they would like to have the option of adding their My Site to the Office open and save dialogs. They can then easily work with their documents directly in this location.